# C# Word Add-In Custom TaskPane Background worker speed issue

Tags: c#, background, com, ms-word, backgroundworker

I have a word add-in, written in C#. When the user picks an option from the ribbon a custom task pane (user control) opens within the application (Word).

From this task pane, they press run, and the active document gets analyzed in a series of fairly complex ways. Checks such as interrogating any bold text in the document and many more. When running the whole process can take anything from 5 seconds to 1 minute, depending on the document. This is fine, no-one has an issue with this.

The problem comes when we try and implement a cancel button. To do this I have tried using a background worker. Everything works.... except that when communicating with the document from the thread (background worker) it is around 7-8 times slower than it was when running from the main thread. I have not been able to find much info on this, any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried other avenues (open xml) but these are not viable options (we have to deal with .doc as well as .docx)

Thanks

---

To give an example:

I have a button on the taskpane (Run).

That calls private void btnRun_Click

That in turn, sets off the background worker backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

In the do work method of the background worker, I have code such as:

myClass.Method()

In myClass would be a line of code such as:

For each Word.Field in ActiveDocument.Fields

That might take, say, 1 second to run from the main button click thread, and up to 30 seconds to run from the background worker. All other code works in good time, it is only code that accesses the Word document that seems to have problems

Comment: Its difficult to say why its slower without seeing the code. You may be doing a lot of cross-threading calls that didn't exist when the operations ran in the foreground thread, or any number of other reasons. Without seeing the code, its going to be difficult to tell you how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for answering Ron. Basically the parts that are slow are any lines of code that access the word document. I will amend my post above with an example

Comment: Have you tried a profiler to see where the calls are that take the most time?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the background thread is running is a different COM apartment than Word's STA.

Another approach you might want to consider is to show the dialog, then proceed with the processing in the same thread, having Windows messages pumped from time to time (e.g. at the beginning of long, possibly nested loops).

When the user presses the button, you set a flag, that you should check regularly throughout the code (possibly right after where you process messages).

You may need to implement UI modality yourself:

1. Display your window with e.g. Word as the owning window, and make sure it's focused
2. Disable the owning window

When you're done processing:

1. Enable the owning window
2. Close your window

Don't pump messages between steps 1 and 2 of either stage.